# Is there any way of preventing .csv files being converted into excel format

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

1. I'm trying to work with an automated testing tool which can use .csv files as its data sourse.
2. After saving a notepad file containing a number of fields and data seperated by commas as .csv it appears to have been converted to an excel file.
3. When I run the test, only the first line of values is identified and can be run within the automated test.

Not sure if this is expected with the testing product (www.badboy.co.au), but just wondered if there was a way of preventing excel from taking control of the .csv file?

Any helpfull feedback would be great.

Comment: " it appears to have been converted to an excel file." Can you please expand on this? Do you mean that it opens with excel or that the extension turns into .xls?

Answer (score 9):

Excel isn't actually "taking control" of the file - Windows has a file type association of ".csv" to "Excel data". I forget where to manage those associations, but the only practical effect it has os to make Excel the default handler for that file (and to change the file icon) when you double-click to open it. It's easy enough to change or void that association once you find out where in the OS it is.

Comment: ^ This is the correct answer ^ Excel isn't taking control of the file, it is just associated with .csv as the default program to open that file. You can change this, but is isn't necessary. As to your program only importing 1 row, Do you have a trial of the software, or is it a full version? Additionally, make sure (in the settings of your program) that you have the appropriate line terminator set up... Usually to indicate a new row, a different character than a comma is used.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to associate .CSV files with something other than Excel.  If you are using Windows, right-click the file and select `Open With...` then point it to something besides Excel, such as Notepad.exe.